# Change icon for file from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, shortcut-file

I am trying to create the URL file with a custom icon but, for some reason, it is not working.
This is my code:

```
#Downloading ico file
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.DownloadFile("url location of the icon file","C:\Users\Public\Pictures\filename.ico")

#Creating URL file
$wshShell = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"
$urlShortcut = $wshShell.CreateShortcut(
  (Join-Path $wshShell.SpecialFolders.Item("AllUsersDesktop") "myname.url")
)
$urlShortcut.TargetPath = "https://somewebsite"
$urlShortcut.IconLocation = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\filename.ico"
$urlShortcut.Save()
```

The icon file is downloaded, and the URL file is created but, the image is not changed. I've tried a few different things with no luck.

Would be nice if anyone has some input on this.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.IconLocation` property isn't supported in your case, but there's a workaround:

```
# ... icon download code omitted

$shortcutFile = Join-Path $wshShell.SpecialFolders.Item('AllUsersDesktop') 'myname.url'
$iconFile = 'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\filename.ico'

$wshShell = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"
$urlShortcut = $wshShell.CreateShortcut($shortcutFile)
$urlShortcut.TargetPath = 'https://en.wikipedia.org'
$urlShortcut.Save()

# This updates the .url file directly to emulate what assigning 
# an icon interactively, via File Explorer, does.
@"
IconIndex=0
HotKey=0
IconFile=$iconFile
"@ | Add-Content -LiteralPath $shortcutFile
```

When you create a *URL* shortcut file (extension `.url`):

- Only *one* writable property is supported by the resulting [`WshUrlShortcut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/265a4017.aspx) object, namely `TargetPath`, which stores the target URL.
- Notably, this prevent use of the `IconLocation` property, which is only available on *executable* shortcut files (extension `.lnk`), which are [`WshShortcut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6kst2k.aspx) objects.

However, the `.url` file format *does* support custom icons (by default, the default browser's icon is used), but that requires assigning them *interactively*, via File Explorer.

Fortunately, `.url` files are plain-text, `.ini`-like files, so it's easy to programmatically update that file directly, so as to emulate the results of interactively assigning an icon, as shown above.

---

*Alternatively* - which may or may not be an option in your case - you can create a regular shortcut file, with extension `.lnk`, which - perhaps surprisingly - also works with URLs assigned to `.TargetPath`. Assigning to `.IconLocation` then works as usual.
However, there are ramifications:

- Obviously, you'll end up with a different filename extension, and the shortcut file won't be readily recognizable as a *URL* shortcut by its extension.
- `.lnk` files are *binary* files.
- `.lnk` files with *URLs* as their target path inexplicably don't allow the URL to be edited via File Explorer later.